# HTML5 Canvas issues with InternetExplorer

Tags: internet-explorer, html5-canvas

I have a constant issue with running my html5 Canvas web app in IE. Works like a charm in all other web-browsers. My IE is version 9.

The issue comes in the following line of code:-

```
    var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
              ctx = can.getContext("2d"),
```

Error Message:-
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getContext'.

Code structure:-

```
(step1) Accept userID from Session variable.
(step2) Call Ajax function to post variable into a WebMethod on the Server side.
(step3) Web method does some queries and returns member classes with values as a JSON formatted string.
(step4) Parse these values and store them in variables on the client side.
(step5) Define canvas.
            var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
                               ctx = can.getContext("2d"),
                               dragging = false,
                               translated = 0,
                               lastX = 0;
            // When a new query is ran, and the elements of the canvas are reprinted the following line of code will prevent the canvas 'bleeding effect'. //    
            can.width = can.width;


grid = (function (dX, dY) {
                // defining a new canvas inside our main canvas
                var can = document.createElement("canvas"),
                        ctx = can.getContext('2d');
                // defining width, height for new canvas
                can.width = dX;
                can.height = dY;
                // fill canvas color
                ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
                ctx.fillRect(0, 0, dX, dY);
                // sets the width of the lines that make up the grid
                ctx.lineWidth = 0.4;
                // sets the color of the lines that make up the grid
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'silver';
                // x axis
                ctx.moveTo(.5, 0.5);
                ctx.lineTo(dX + .5, 0.5);
                ctx.stroke();
                // y axis
                ctx.moveTo(.5, .5);
                ctx.lineTo(.5, dY + .5);
                ctx.stroke();
                // To create a pattern with the HTML5 Canvas, we can use the createPattern() method of the canvas context which returns a pattern object.
                return ctx.createPattern(can, 'repeat');
            })(72, 25); // size of each grid.
            ctx.save();

 function timeline1() {
                // fill canvas color
                ctx.fillStyle = "black";
                ctx.fillRect(-translated, 0, 930, 570);
                // setting the canvas to be filled with the previously defined x-y grid.  
                ctx.fillStyle = grid;
                ctx.fillRect(-translated, -250, 930, 2 * can.height);
                // setting the style for y co-ordinate labelling 
                ctx.fillStyle = "White";
                ctx.font = "11px monospace";
                // y co-ordinate labels - , etc... //
                ctx.fillText("L1", -translated, 310);
                ctx.fillText("L2", -translated, 285);
                ctx.fillText("L3", -translated, 260);
                ctx.fillText("L4", -translated, 235);




// when mouse is clicked on canvas
                can.onmousedown = function (e) {
                    var evt = e || event;
                    // dragging is set to true.
                    dragging = true;
                    //                        lastX = evt.offsetX;
                    lastX = evt.offsetX == undefined ? evt.layerX : evt.offsetX;
                    return false;
                }
                // when mouse is clicked again and the canvas is deselected
                window.onmouseup = function () {
                    // dragging is set to false.
                    dragging = false;
                    return false;
                }
                // when mouse is dragging the canvas sideways //
                window.onmousemove = function (e) {
                    var evt = e || event;
                    if (dragging) {
                        //                            var delta = evt.offsetX - lastX;
                        var delta = (evt.offsetX == undefined ? evt.layerX : evt.offsetX) - lastX;
                        translated += delta;
                        move(ctx, 930, 900);
                        //                            lastX = evt.offsetX;
                        lastX = evt.offsetX == undefined ? evt.layerX : evt.offsetX;
                        timeline1();;
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                // common code used to service either canvas
                function move(context, width, height) {
                    context.restore();
                    context.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
                    context.save();
                    context.translate(translated, 0);

                }
(step6) Finally use other functions to draw data on canvas using variables sent by the WEbMethod.
```

I m programming via Microsoft Visual Studios 2010. Using C# and Javascript.

I also use JQuery.

Any ideas why this is the issue?

I have been able to fix it by restoring my IE settings to default factory settings, or restoring advanced settings. The web app starts working for a couple of weeks or so and again same issue. Changing compatibility view doesn't change anything.

Comment: *JScript* runtime error? JScript is Microsofts proprietary dialect of Javascript. Maybe your script is interpreted wrong? Please confirm that the `<script>` tag which loads/surrounds the script has the property `type="text/javascript"`?

Comment: yes the script type is javascript

Answer (score 0):

You are probably loading/invoking the script before the DOM is fully loaded. The variable result can be related to cache as well as how the browser(s) are loading the script.

You are not showing enough code to pinpoint the problem but try to move your custom script to the bottom of the page, or use something like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {

    var can = document.getElementById("myCanvas"),
        ctx = can.getContext("2d"),
        ...

});
```

Comment: basically this approach doesn't work because I have a lot of nested functionalities. I will try to update my code in the original question to give a sense of what i am try to do.

Comment: OK I have added a pseudo code for the structure of my canvas app.